# HelloSign get template/document preview link

Tags: hellosign-api

Is there a way to preview a template or a signed document using API?

I know there is a way to download/get a link to template files but can't find any info about how to download/preview a template itself (or a signed document).

I also know that there is the embedded template API, but I don't want to allow users to create/edit a template, just to preview the existing one.

For documents, I only found a way to preview a document on the home page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm a HelloSign API Support engineer, happy to help!

There's no way to preview the template outside of previewing it on HelloSign.com from your dashboard.

You can use the Get Signature Request endpoint (https://app.hellosign.com/api/reference#get_signature_request) to view info on a specific signature request, and you can also use the Get Files endpoint (https://app.hellosign.com/api/reference#get_files) to get a current copy of the documents from a specific signature request too.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a `GET /signature_request/files/[:signature_request_id]` API to get current documents by a signature request.
Not ideal, but hopefully will solve my needs